# Open a SharePoint classic experience in FullScreen Mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages

I am looking to embed a SharePoint classic experience Calendar on an Modern SharePoint Page and one of the ways that I thought of is to embed the server side rendered calendar within a Modern Page.

[image: Text]

Is there a way to open the classic experience page in FullScreen by default?

By, possibly, appending some option in the query string?
I know that when the FullScreen Button is pressed, all it does is append a class called `ms-fullscreenmode` to the Body of the document like the one below

[image: Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append **?IsDlg=1** to calendar URL like:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/Events/calendar.aspx?IsDlg=1
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: hello Ganesh, thanks for the query option. It worked and i can postpone all the work of transfering entries to an events list for the future.
It would have been nice if the category could be shown also, but i have written the colour coding of the categories on a text web part that will be rendered on the side of the page.
Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: the only unfortunate drawback is the fact the the scroll bar is not shown, but thats a natural thing since it is destined to be shown in a modal window.
If you set the iframe on the page with pixelated limits in the feight attribute it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

To open the classic experience page in full screen by default, you could place the following JavaScript code in a Script Editor Web Part,  the code snippet will cause the screen to go to focused full screen mode when the page is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    SetFullScreenMode(true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Emily thanks for your contribution, but since i am trying to avoid the overhead work of transfering entries onto an events list and deploying an spf react calendar just to show the dates, i try to avoid most of the scripts that might break the modern experience.|
Thanks again!