# Adding calendar webpart into custom SharePoint homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, calendar, sitepages, classic-experience

So I'm trying to figure out a way to put a SharePoint calendar (or rather SharePoint Event List) into my custom home page. Basically, my home page has a tabbed section and on one of the tabs, I want to include a web part or something of the sort.

Each tab is different, one has buttons which open links, another tab has a table with contact information, another tab has a weather widget, and on the last tab, I want it to show our public calendar, but I can't figure out a way to just get the calendar portion.

I have tried using an `<iframe...>` but that doesn't work.  I've tried other things, but can't get them to work. I've got enough knowledge in SharePoint and HTML to be dangerous, and if I don't understand something, I can figure it out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this modern experience page or classic page? How did you add the tabs on home page? Also, your event list is classic "Calendar" list or custom list with calendar view?

Comment: My page is Classic and I added the tabs through the Embed code webpart.  I didn't build the calendar, it was there when i started, but it says it's an Event List and it has a default calendar view.

Comment: Ah classic page, it would have been easier to add tabs on modern pages with this upcoming feature - [SharePoint: Collapsible sections on modern pages](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/sharepoint-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/).

Comment: Did you try adding `iframe` like this: `<iframe src="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>`? You can find full embed code at: [Add Modern Calendar to a SharePoint Online page](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/15/add-modern-calendar-to-a-sharepoint-online-page/).

Comment: Yeah, I got into this position and the site was already established and the managers don't know when/if they will be transitioning to the modern page.  But in regards to this, that one does show the page with the calendar view on it, but it shows the whole page, top nav bar, left nav bar, and all the other items on the page, not just the calendar.

Comment: Try adding **?IsDlg=1** at the end of calendar URL like I mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294221/open-a-sharepoint-classic-experience-in-fullscreen-mode/294227#294227). let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This gets me closer to what I'm looking for.  Basically, the page is managed by a different section and they have on the ViewName.aspx page a blurb of text above the calendar and that blurb is present when I use the code above.  Is there a way to just have the calendar?

Comment: Can you show me how it is looking currently by adding screenshot to your question? Also add the current code you are using.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Gpiwpre   

And which part of my code?

Comment: Ok, so i found a partial solution.  To use an anchor. Basically after the ?IsDLG=1 i put #WPQ4_nav_header and it is showing what I'm looking for.  I just don't know if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I will write our discussion/comments as an answer below.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `iframe` code like this:

```
<iframe
    src="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx"
    width="100%"
    height="600">
</iframe>
```

You can find full embed code at: [Add Modern Calendar to a SharePoint Online page](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/15/add-modern-calendar-to-a-sharepoint-online-page/)

**Update**:

To hide navigation & see the calendar in full screen/expanded mode, add **?IsDlg=1** at the end of calendar URL like:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx?IsDlg=1
```